# Why does the Windows crate contain compiled static libraries?

Tags: windows, rust, rust-cargo, windows-rs

The [windows](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate, which provides Rust bindings to the Windows API, is split into a few internal crates, one of them being the [windows-targets](https://crates.io/crates/windows-targets). This create is also split in a few [internal crates](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/tree/master/crates/targets), and these are loaded according to the target platform.

These platform-dependent crates don't seem to do much: they simply pass `cargo:rustc-link-search=native={LIB_DIR}` to the compiler.

Now looking at these `LIB_DIR` directories, they contain an already-compiled static library, one for each platform. Example: [windows.0.48.0.lib](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/tree/master/crates/targets/x86_64_msvc/lib) file.

I couldn't find any documentation regarding this, but I suppose these static libraries are compiled from the C source files found in the [`baseline`](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/tree/master/crates/targets/baseline) directory, which contain... a duplication of the Windows API function declarations in C. That's intriguing.

The Rust bindings themselves are written somewhere else, like [here (GDI bindings)](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/blob/master/crates/libs/windows/src/Windows/Win32/Graphics/Gdi/mod.rs).

**Question:** these compiled C static libraries seem to be a duplication of the API already available in Windows, so why are they necessary?

Comment: Do you mean "duplication" or "wrapper"?

Comment: @tadman I mean "duplication". The C code already exists in Windows, in theory we should need just the Rust bindings.

Comment: Those are **import** libraries. They contain the function names alongside the module name that exports those functions. The linker uses import libraries to build the import tables in the final executable image.

Comment: @IInspectable I know, but you don't need them. The bindings work perfectly fine just with the [Rust declarations](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/blob/master/crates/libs/windows/src/Windows/Win32/Graphics/Gdi/mod.rs). Those import libs must be there for some other reason.

Comment: No, that's the reason why they are required. There are [many ways](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/issues/1720#issuecomment-1485373474) a program can successfully link without an explicit dependency on `windows-targets` (see [this PR](https://github.com/Amanieu/parking_lot/pull/378) for more rationale), but that will eventually break. That is, until [`raw_dylib`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/raw-dylib.html) becomes stable, at which point import libraries are no longer needed.

Comment: It seems like you don't quite understand the term *"import library"*. Those are libraries that strictly contain import information. There is no code in import libraries. The program you posted [here](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/issues/2443) links as long as you have a Windows SDK installed, or some other build system managed to pull in the respective import libraries (Rust's Standard Library only needs a handful of imports). I guess you can make it fail if you build it on a Linux system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a response by [asking directly](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/issues/2443) the official [windows crate](https://crates.io/crates/windows) maintainers:

> While the GNU and MSVC toolchains often provide some import libs to support C++ development, those lib files are often incomplete, missing, or just plain wrong. This can lead to linker errors that are very difficult to diagnose. The `windows-targets` crate ensures that all functions defined by the `windows` and `windows-sys` crates can be linked without relying on implicit lib files distributed by the toolchain.

For anyone interested, further details can be seen [here](https://kennykerr.ca/rust-getting-started/understanding-windows-targets.html).